# Can't find s4-ribbonrow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I need to hide the ribbon from users without at least ManageWeb permissions.

I saw this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2012/04/30/how-to-hide-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-rajeswari-mohandas/) which looked like what I wanted.

It says to find the tag with an id of `"s4-ribbonrow"` on the master page and wrap it with this

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl PermissionsString="ManageWeb" runat="server">...</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

But I can't find a tag with that id anywhere. Not in the html file that gets converted into the masterpage, and not in the masterpage file as well. But I CAN find it in the source code of the served page. Note, I am using Office 365 SharePoint or online SharePoint and I believe it's now 2016 version. Also, this site has publishing enabled. So has the id for the ribbon changed? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to find `<div id="ms-designer-ribbon">`
- Surround it with this tag `SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl` to looks the following

[image]

For more details, check

- [How to hide SharePoint 2013 Ribbon via CSS ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/12/hide-ribbon-sharepoint-2013-using-css/)
- [Stack the SharePoint Suite Bar on top of Ribbon – SharePoint Online / Office 365](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/09/stack-suite-bar-on-ribbon-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. That works, except that it hides the suite bar as well as the ribbon. Is the top suite bar considered part of the ribbon?

Comment: ms-designer-ribbon is the parent div for suit bar and ribbon , what's the sharepoint version that you are using ?

Comment: sharepoint online via office 365, so I believe it's now 2016, or at least 2013

Comment: I have updated my  answer with a good link for SharePoint online , please check it , and don't hesitate to tell me if you need any clarification .

Comment: I don't want to hide it from everybody, I want me (admin) to see it, so it needs to be permissions based. That link shows you how to hide it from everyone if you do it via css. I'll mark the answer as accepted because it does hide the ribbon, I just didn't know it was an all or nothing thing.

Comment: Thanks , meanwhile I found something that may help you , try to add the below css code in script editor at any page that you need to hide only ribbon that working for me but in master page not working ! only the above mentioned that working in masterpage but it hide both as you said <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server"PermissionsString="FullMask"> <style type="text/css"> #suiteBarTop{display:block !important;} #s4-ribbonrow{display:none !important;} </style> </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>